# ファイルから読み込んだ数値とその数値をソートした結果を出力したいのだが、うまくできない。

Tags: c

ファイルから読み込んだ数値とその数値をソートした結果を出力したいのですが、ソートの結果が出力されません。
私は以下のようにプログラムをしました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

const int NMOJI=50;
const int MAX_ITEM=100;

typedef struct student{
    char name[100];
    double value;
    double weight;
} Student;

void swap_Student(Student *x, Student *y){
    Student tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

void sort_by_name(Student a[], int n){
   
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = n - 1; j > i; j--){
            if(strcmp(a[j - 1].name, a[j].name) > 0) swap_Student(&a[j - 1], &a[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    Student std[256];
    int i,nitem=0;
    double capacity;
    double weight,value,kati=value/weight;
    char file_name[NMOJI],name[100];
    printf("Data Flie Name: ");
    scanf("%s",file_name);
    if((fp=fopen(file_name,"r"))==NULL){
        printf("%s:そのファイルを開けることはできません。\n",file_name);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Knapsack capacity: ");  scanf("%lf",&capacity);
    printf("データファイル名： %s\n",file_name);
    printf("ナップサック容量： %f\n",capacity);
   
     fscanf(fp,"%d",&nitem);
    if(nitem>MAX_ITEM){
        printf("アイテム数を%3d以下にしてください.\n",MAX_ITEM);
        return -1;
    } 
    else{
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s%lf%lf",std[nitem].name,&std[nitem].weight,&std[nitem].value)==3){
          printf("%-10s %5.1f %5.1f\n",std[nitem].name,std[nitem].weight,std[nitem].value);  
    }
     sort_by_name(std, nitem);
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s%lf%lf",std[nitem].name,&std[nitem].weight,&std[nitem].value)==3)
        printf("%-10s %5.1f %5.1f\n", std[i].name, std[i].weight, std[i].value);
    }
     fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

<結果>

```
$ ./a.out
Data Flie Name: knap10.txt
Knapsack capacity: 121
データファイル名： knap10.txt
ナップサック容量： 121.000000
一番      39.0  42.0
二番      13.0  12.0
三番      68.0  45.0
四番      15.0   5.0
五番      10.0   2.0
六番      20.0  61.0
七番      31.0  89.0
八番      15.0  32.0
九番      41.0  47.0
十番      16.0  18.0
```

参考書等参考にしながら実装したので、変なところはないと思うのですが、どの箇所が間違っていますか。
回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: プログラムは人間が書いた通りにしか動きません。意図した通りに動かないなら、十中八九は書いた人間がミスしています。 / 「参考書等を見たから(自分は)間違ってないはず」という思い込みは、今後のためにも捨てた方が良いと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「読み込んだデータそのまま」までは表示できていて、「ソート後のデータが表示できていない」のでおかしいのは以下の箇所。

```
    else{
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s%lf%lf",std[nitem].name,&std[nitem].weight,&std[nitem].value)==3){
            printf("%-10s %5.1f %5.1f\n",std[nitem].name,std[nitem].weight,std[nitem].value);  
        }
        sort_by_name(std, nitem);
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s%lf%lf",std[nitem].name,&std[nitem].weight,&std[nitem].value)==3)
            printf("%-10s %5.1f %5.1f\n", std[i].name, std[i].weight, std[i].value);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

- 定義した `sort_by_name` を呼び出した後に、なぜか `fscanf` で再びファイルから読み込もうとしている
- 一回目の `while + fscanf` で読み込んだ後に `fclose` していないので、(二回目の) ファイルの読み取り開始位置は前回の続き = ファイルの最後から
- 既に読み取るデータが無いので何も表示されない

ソート後のデータを表示するようにプログラムを修正しましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。すでに読み取るデータがなく、もとのデータとソートした後のデータを同時に二つ表示するのは不可能なため、ソート後のデータを表示するようなプログラムを作成しなさい、という認識でいいでしょうか。